# How can I disable/hide certain themes in multisite?

Tags: theme-development, multisite

How can I disable/hide certain themes in multisite? I only want certain themes to be used for now.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable certain themes in your WordPress network.

Go to `http://www.yournetwork.com/wp-admin/network/themes.php` click on 'network disable' to hide the themes for the other websites.

You can enable a theme for a single site by searching for the site -> click on 'themes' -> click enable at the desired theme.

Hope this helps.